# Marklogic JSON document field index

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a ML database with all json documents.. I am having an issue with field creation for this documents.. Say I have a document

```
{
    "id": "1452016",
    "name": "ALEXA488",
    "identifyingInfo": {
        "preparation": {
            "chemicalConjugations": [{
                "name": "ALEXA 488"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I created a field for top level json element `name` ..

```
{
 "field-name": "concept_name",
 "field-path": [
  {
    "path": "/name",
    "weight": 1
  }
  ],
  "word-lexicon" :["http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1"]
}
```

I created a field range index as well on this field..

Now when I do the search like this

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";


let $search := ' (concept_name:(*ALEXA*))'

let $options :=
   <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <constraint name="collection">
        <collection prefix=""/>
    </constraint>
    <constraint name="concept_name">
        <word>
            <field name="concept_name" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1"/>
        </word>
    </constraint>
    <term>
        <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>whitespace-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
    </term>
    <return-facets>false</return-facets>
    <return-values>false</return-values>
    <return-constraints>false</return-constraints>
    <return-frequencies>false</return-frequencies>
    <return-qtext>false</return-qtext>
    <search-option>format-json</search-option>
    <search-option>score-simple</search-option>
</options>

let $start := 1
let $page-length :=1

 let $result := search:search($search, $options, $start, $page-length)  

return $result
```

The search is matching the top level `name` and also `identifyingInfo/preparation/chemicalConjugations/name`..

What should be the field path, so that it only matches the top level json element, in this case `name` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your field path looks fine.  You can check that with

```
cts:field-value-match("concept_name", "*")
```

But you're trying to use wildcards.  Did you enable "trailing wildcard searches" on your field?  Do you also want "one/two/three character searches" enabled?

Comment: My main concern is, it is also matching the child element `name (dentifyingInfo/preparation/chemicalConjugations/name)` and I want to only match at the top level `name`. I was wondering if I need to specify anything else on the field to tell it to match only top level element.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. Replace your constraint with:

```
<constraint name="concept_name">
  <value>
    <field name="concept_name" />
  </value>
</constraint>
```

In your field, turn on **field value searches** and **trailing wildcard searches**.

I created three docs in a database; one just like your sample, one that had "ALEXA" only in /name, and one that had "ALEXA" only in the other name. My test correctly found the two documents.

Comment: Does your search snippet also show hit in the other name when your document has ALEXA in the top name and other name ? For me when I changed the constraint to `value` instead of `word` I get no hits... `  stemmed searches: basic`, `word searches`, `field value searches`,` field value positions`, `fast phrase searches`, `trailing wildcard searches`, `trailing wildcard word positions`, `three character searches` turned on.

Comment: when I do 
search:resolve(search:parse($search, $options))/@total
fn:count(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:query(search:parse($search, $options))))

I get different count, and the cts:search count is the right count

Comment: The @total is an estimate, driven by index resolution; the fn:count uses filtering. See [Fast Pagination and Unfiltered Searches](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered#chapter) for more details. There might be indexes you can turn on to make the numbers be the same.

Comment: oka, but I am still confused as to why search:search is matching on text that is not in the field.